# Is it appropriate to assess internal consistency on related items measured with different response formats within the same instrument?

Tags: reliability, psychometrics

In my survey, I grouped 67 unique counseling techniques that I thought were related to one another (based on theory and conceptual similarity) into six "counseling domains" using fairly intuitive, descriptive but brief labels (e.g., rapport-building or confrontation). In the first section of the survey, I asked respondents how frequently they used these techniques on a five-point scale (1=never, 5= always).

The other major section of the survey included three vignettes or scenarios where key variables were changed between them were created and respondents were asked to choose which of the 67 techniques they would employ in those situations. These variables, then, are 0/1 dummies.

I would like to demonstrate that the six domains are meaningful and useful constructs, and I'm thinking that reliability analysis is the way to do this. Would it be appropriate to obtain alphas (or some other measure of internal consistency) the domains for the frequency of use subsection (Likert items) **and** each of the three vignettes (dummies)? Or just the frequency of use?

I don't think FA is appropriate because the factors would be based on *the frequency of use* of the techniques, not any latent construct, but this fact may also limit what claims can be made in the reliability analysis as well. Thank you so much for any feedback!

Comment: That will not help you solve the specific problems you asked about but how can a “domain” be a measurable construct? Is it quantitative? Does it have a magnitude? It's also difficult to follow how factor analysis would not be appropriate and yet talking of internal consistency or reliability could be meaningful. In fact, thinking of “frequency of use” or “adherence to a domain” as a latent construct makes much more sense to me and then factor analysis would seem appropriate (at least inasmuch as the structure of your data allows it and you are comfortable doing it directly on items).

Comment: Thanks, Gael, for the thoughts. I may be having difficulty describing my problem, which may be indicative of there not actually being a satisfactory solution to what I'm trying to demonstrate.